# Как сделать тоже самое что делает моя программа, но через конструктор и деструктор?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 10

class Product
    {
        private:
            char  name[30];
            char category[30];
            double price;
            int   number;
        public:
            void getDetails(void);
            void printDetails(void);
            double getPrice()
     {
    return price * number;
    }
};

void Product::getDetails(void) { //запрашиваем данные
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter category: ";
    cin >> category;
    cout << "Enter price: ";
    cin >> price;
    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> number;

}

void Product::printDetails(void) { //вводим данные
    cout << "Product details:\n";
    cout << "Name:" << name << "Category:" << category << ", Price:" << price << ", Number:" << number << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Product prd[MAX];       //массив объектов типа класса Product
    int n, i;
    double sum = 0;

    cout << "Enter total number of products: ";
    cin >> n;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Enter details of product " << i + 1 << ":\n";
        prd[i].getDetails();
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Details of product " << (i + 1) << ":\n";
        prd[i].printDetails();
        sum += prd[i].getPrice();
    }
    cout << "Total price: " << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а что именно делает ваша программа, что вы хотите еще конструктор и деструктор?

Comment: Программа считает общую стоимость всего товара и выводит на экран. А как это будет выглядеть если реализовать программу через конструктор и деструктор?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо разнести сущности

1. добавить конструктор по умолчанию и конструктор с параметрами

   ```
    class Product {
    public:
        Product();
        Product(const char* src_name, const char* src_categoty, const doube src_price, const int src_number);
    };
   ```

В конструкторе по умолчанию вы все члены класса сбросите в 0 или установите какие-нибудь первоначальные параметры (вам виднее что нужно)

В конструкторе с параметрами входные параметры надо присвоить соответствующим членам класса

Теперь пользователь класса может задавать какие ему угодно параметры, а не вызывать метод `getDetails()` для инициализации членов класса

т.е. если вы хотите задать параметры через ввод от пользователя, то используете

```
Product object;
object.getDetails();
```

А если у вас уже есть какие-то параметры и вы хотите указать их классу, то используете

```
Product object("...", "...", 10.0, 15);
```

Только замечание - функция должна сама себя комментировать. Название `getDetails` себя НЕ КОММЕНТИРУЕТ - я скорее подумал бы, что функция вернет что-то на выход, назовите уж лучше тогда `inputDetails` Ж:)

2. касательно деструктора - он в вашей задаче совершенно не нужен, вы не выделяете память или не выполняете какую-то еще работу, требующую ее корректного завершения

Comment: большое спасибо =)